# Placing ticks near interval-labels

Tags: pgfplots

I have to make a plot having ticks at interval-labels (not in the middle of segments between labels). Expected changes are marked in red in the picture below.
BTW: Does exist a method of automatic writing of ticks (not by explicit writing of each point `xtick={1838,1843,etc.}`)?
MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=1838,
    xmax=1862,
    x tick label as interval,
    xticklabel={
        \pgfmathprintnumber\tick\discretionary{--}{--}{--}\pgfmathparse{\nexttick-1}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult
    },
    xtick={1838,1843,1848,1853,1858,1863},
    xticklabel style={
        align=center,
        text width=1cm,
        execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{8pt},
        rotate=90,
        anchor=east
    },
    xmajorgrids,
]
\addplot
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1840    8\\
1845    7\\
1850    6\\
1855    4\\
1860    4\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using functionnalities of the `pgfplotstable` package.

This allows to compute the shift between two entries of the table, assuming these are uniformly spaced.
The shift is then used to virtually compute and typeset the `\nexttick` without calling `x ticklabels as interval`.
The `xtick` is also defined with `xtick=data` which avoids manual input.

Two points which I am not sure of :

- The values of `xticklabels`
- The red crosses on the y-axis

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}

    \begin{document}
    % Get number of rows
    \pgfplotstableread[row sep=crcr]{
        1840    8\\
        1845    7\\
        1850    6\\
        1855    4\\
        1860    4\\
    }\loadedtable

    % Row amount of the source table
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\loadedtable}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval}
    % Number of last row (numbering starts at 0)
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastrow}{\numrows-1}
    % First value in data
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of{\loadedtable}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\databegin}{\pgfplotsretval}
    % Last value in data
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\lastrow}{[index]0}\of{\loadedtable}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\dataend}{\pgfplotsretval}
    % Data step (assumes uniform step)
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\datashift}{(\dataend-\databegin)/(\numrows-1)}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\discretionary{--}{--}{--}\pgfmathparse{\tick+\datashift-1}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult},
                xtick=data,
                xticklabel style={
                    align=center,
                    text width=1cm,
                    execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{8pt},
                    rotate=90,
                    anchor=east,
                    %yshift={\xticklabelyshiftcoeff*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
                    },
                y tick label as interval,
                xmajorgrids,
                enlarge x limits=false,
                clip marker paths=false,
            ]
            \addplot table {\loadedtable};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to denote by crosses that I would like to remove these lines and put the new - you did exactly what I need. Only intervals have to be centered on points of the first data column: for instance, point (1840,4) has to be over the xtick label "1838-1842". It means the mean value taken on years 1838, 1839, 1840, 1841 and 1842.

Comment: Thx! I am very grateful for your answer. I only add 2 lines and replace one - and acheve what I wont.
`/pgf/number format/.cd,
1000 sep={},
xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick-2}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\discretionary{--}{--}{--}\pgfmathparse{\tick+\datashift-3}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult},`

Comment: This is more correct (universal): `xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick-(\datashift-1)/2}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\discretionary{--}{--}{--}\pgfmathparse{\tick+(\datashift-1)/2}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult},`
Strange is that if `\addplot` of table with some `nan` in few last values is executed, referred **vertical grid lines vanish**. To solve this it is sufficient to execute `\addplot` with data that not has any "not a number" **at the first place**, but after execution `\addplot` with full filled table with numerical data.

Comment: Definitions between `\begin{document}` and `\begin{tikzpicture}` give unwanted margin on the side of the picture. While moved before `\begin{document}` everything works OK.

Comment: The "margins" are actually spaces, but yes it is better to put this in the preamble. By the way for standalone `tikzpicture`s it is better to use `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}`. Finally, the behavior you mention about `nan` values is the normal one, see `pgfplots` documentation for `xtick=data`.